# Splitting this string (var1=val1&&var2=val2) using regular expressions in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this string `var1=val1&&var2=val2`. Using java's regular expression support I would like to split the string like this `{val1, val2}`. i.e., the resulting array should contain `val1` and `val2`. In other words, I want to remove the words which end with equals sign and the special character && and I want to do all these with regex. Could someone help me with this please?

Comment: Why do you even need regex? If you know that your values don't contain '&&' you can just do a simple string replacement to ', ' and prepend and append the braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he is asking for regex.. so here is how you do it:

the regex provided is only if the variables are only 2 variables long (IE, the string to split follows the exact same pattern as you provided).
for Regex in java, you use the Pattern and the Matcher classes.

```
String[] vars = {"", ""};

String toCheck = "var1=val1&&var2=val2";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?=(.*?).*?=(.*$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(toCheck);

while(m.find()){
    vars[0] = m.group(1);
    vars[1] = m.group(2);
}
```

a VERY useful tool I use is this: http://myregexp.com/signedJar.html

if you don't fully understand regex its hard to get your head around it.. but just take your time and test things out with that java applet ^. it compiles your regex in realtime and is really informative =)

*Note: that regex will match no matter what the "var1", "var2", "val1" and "val2" are.
EG:  it will match: username=derpa&&password=herpa

and the output would make the array be like: {derpa, herpa}

best of luck.. I hated regex, now I use them all the time :D

[EDIT]

for multiple variables, this is how I would do it:

```
        ArrayList<String> vars = new ArrayList<String>();

        String toCheck = "var1=val1&&var2=val2&&var3=val3&&var4=val4";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)=(.*?)&&|(.*?)=(.*?)$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(toCheck);

        while(m.find()){
            String val = m.group(2);
            if(val == null)
                vars.add((m.group(4)));
            else
                vars.add(val);
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < vars.size(); j++){
            System.out.println(vars.get(j));
        }
```

this is tested and works.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Lets say I have more. for instance, I have var1=val1&&var2=val2&&var3=val3&&var4=val4 and this changes every time. Could someone help me with a solution to the problem I just mentioned. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use `split()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "var1=val1&&var2=val2";
    String[] exp = s.split("&&");
    String[] values = new String[] {exp[0].split("=")[1], exp[1].split("=")[1]};
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(values)); //prints [val1, val2]
}
```